# Show Amount upto two decimal places without rounding off in DataGrid

Tags: c#, datagrid, floating-point, formatting, double

Say for example i have a large number 12345678.88 right now when i display it in the Datagrid

with the use of

```
  <asp:Label ID="txtlineAmt" runat="server" ReadOnly="true" Text='<%# Eval("DtaLineAmount", "{0:F}") %>'></asp:Label>
```

This number is getting display as 12345680.00 How do i display it as it is 12345678.88 even if the number becomes 12345678.88888

I saw the below code somewhere to solve my issue but don't know how to use it

```
result=string.Format("{0:0.0}",Math.Truncate(value*10)/10);
```

Comment: you can do it on your db side if you like ...select CAST(Value AS decimal(10,2))

Comment: can we do it without Casting??

Comment: select convert(decimal(value,2)) as result

Comment: <%# Format(Cdec(Convert.ToString(DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "FieldName")))),"#.##") %>'